# Display data from SQL query in an HTML table in PHP

Tags: php, html

I retrieved a list of data from an SQL database and now I would like to display it in a neat table rather than in a list. I managed to find a way to do this (probably not very elegant, though), but the column headers seem to be offset and I have not idea how to fix this.

[image]

I'm completely new to PHP, so any hints on how to solve this will be much appreciated!

```
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>';
    echo '<td>Word</td>';
    echo '<td>Frequency</td>';
    echo '</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $response = $db->query("SELECT * FROM frequencies WHERE freq BETWEEN 900 AND 910 ORDER BY freq");

    while ($row = $response->fetch())
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['word'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['freq'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    $response->closeCursor();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<th>` element is a **table header** element and should be used **instead** of `<td>` (**table data**) element in your header row - it should never be a wrapper around `<td>` elements.

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Word</th>';
echo '<th>Frequency</th>';
echo '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer combining php and html

```
<table >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >Word</th>
            <th >Frequency</th>   
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <?php
        $response = $db->query("SELECT * FROM frequencies WHERE freq 
        BETWEEN 900 AND 910 ORDER BY freq");

        ?>
    <tbody>
        <?php  
 while ( $row = $response->fetch()) { 
         ?>
           <tr>

            <td><?php echo $row['word']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['freq']; ?></td>

         </tr>
          <?php } 

            $response->closeCursor();

           ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```